# Ошибка при запуске PgAdmin4

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, pgadmin4

Стоит наверное уточнить, что качал с офф сайта инсталяшку, которая установила postgresql + pgAdmin4

Данная ошибка вылетает во время запуска. Вот скрин  https://skr.sh/s88iU3k6wc9

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "D:\v5\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "D:\v5\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "D:\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "D:\v5\python\python.exe -s D:\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_10780_MOTVKDKQFACMWOEV
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Произошел сбой NW.js. Перезапустить?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-MUQHR93
  - ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  - DataGrip: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2020.1\bin;
  - DokanLibrary1: C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.1.0\
  - DokanLibrary1_LibraryPath_x64: C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.1.0\lib\
  - DokanLibrary1_LibraryPath_x86: C:\Program Files\Dokan\Dokan Library-1.1.0\x86\lib\
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\Alex
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-MUQHR93
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - NVM_HOME: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm
  - NVM_SYMLINK: C:\Program Files\nodejs
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\Alex\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.2.3\bin;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2020.1\bin;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.1.1\bin;
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 14e86c8d-79fd-4acd-ae47-d31a182a0554
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 50522
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PhpStorm: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2020.1.1\bin;
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 3c03
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files\Intel\
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
  - TEMP: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-MUQHR93
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-MUQHR93
  - USERNAME: Alex
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\Alex
  - WebStorm: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2019.2.3\bin;
  - windir: C:\WINDOWS
  - __COMPAT_LAYER: DetectorsAppHealth
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "D:\v5\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "D:\v5\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, не проходите мимо. Если кто знает - хоть мысли подкиньте.
Уже не знаю куда копать.

Пробовал даже на чистую винду ставить. Ошибка та же.

Пробовал:

1. Менять порты
2. Устанавливать версии чуть младше
3. Переустанавливал необходимые дрова для PG
4. Останавливал / запускал службы

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте старую версию пг админа.
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.30/windows/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [вот этот совет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559636/pgadmin4-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-value). А именно:

1. удалить файл

```
C:\Users{User name}\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db
```

2. добавить переменную окружения

```
SQLITE_PATH = 'C:\Users{User name}\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db'
```